# Django: how to make part of the template visible only for admin

Tags: django

I  have a template html file and i want to make part of it only visible to admin user.

As far as i understand the default way is to write:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
    code code code...
{% endif %}
```

but sadly it wont work.

This is my view:

```
@login_required
def lessonsLOG(request):
    return render_to_response('NlessonsLOG.html', 
                              {'full_name': request.user.username, 'lessons': Lesson.objects.all() })
```

Please help, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
    code code code...
{% endif %}
```

And in views.py add this:

```
@login_required
def pamokosLOG(request):
    return render(request, 'NEpamokosLOG.html', 
                              {'full_name': request.user.username, 'pamokos': Pamoka.objects.all() })
```

Comment: There is not `user` in his template context.

Comment: @aumo could you suggest how do i add it in the context?

Comment: @ppt I added an answer

Comment: thanks @jatin , your views.py fix helped me. Maybe you know why didnt the original way` render_to_response(` didnt work?

Comment: @pptt render_to_response wroks for same but you forgot to add context_instance.

Comment: The syntx of render_to_response is:
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          {....},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 2):

Current user can be accessible by `request.user` if your add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

And if you want to check superuser status, use is_superuser and is_staff:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff and request.user.is_superuser %}
    code
{% endif %}
```

Do not forget to assign those attributes to your users.

Comment: He stated in his question that `{% if request.user.is_staff %}` did not work